# Correct use of java.util.scanner in a loop?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainMenu {

    public MainMenu(){

        int x = 1;
        Scanner menuIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        while ( x == 1 ){

            String pick = "0";

            System.out.println("--==  Household Admin v1.0 ==--");
            System.out.println("(A)dd Resident");
            System.out.println("(R)emove Resident");
            System.out.println("(L)ist Resident(s)");

            System.out.println("pick = " + pick);

            System.out.print("#: ");

            pick = menuIn.nextLine();

            System.out.println("pick = " + pick);

            switch (pick) {
                case "A":
                case "a":
                        Resident.residentList.add( Resident.newResident() );
                        break;
                case "R":
                case "r":
                        break;
                case "L":
                case "l":
                        break;
                case "Q":
                case "q":
                        x = 0;
                        break;
                default:
                        System.out.println("WRONG! Try again.");
                        break;
            }
        }
        menuIn.close();
    }
}
```

The first time through the loop everything works as expected.  The second time throught the loop I am getting:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
>       at household.MainMenu.(MainMenu.java:26)
>       at household.MyFirstGame.main(MyFirstGame.java:7)

I am not sure how to "reset" the scanner object as to be able to reuse it again.

Comment: Irrelevant but just use `true` as a condition in your while loop.

Comment: I didn't want to do that, because I wanted to give a switch option to exit.

Comment: You could always use `System.exit(0)`

Comment: Check `if(menuIn.hasNextLine())` before doing `pick = menuIn.nextLine();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your whole code in constructor of `MainMenu` in which you are closing the scanner by calling `menuIn.close();` which is the root cause.

It seems you are creating new instances of `MainMenu` from `main` method inside `MyFirstGame`. Now if you call `.close()` on scanner object, it closes the underlying stream. So your first object gets created successfully. But when you try to instantiate second object of `MainMenu` you get this exception since `System.in` stream has been closed.

Ideally you should use single scanner object for reading user inputs. Instead of creating new scanner object in constructor every time, just create a single scanner object in main method and pass it as argument to the constructor. Something like below.

inside `MyFirstGame.main`

```
Scanner menuIn = new Scanner(System.in);
MainMenu mainMenu1= new MainMenu(menuIn);
MainMenu mainMenu2= new MainMenu(menuIn);
//.... and So on

//and close scanner object here once you have created all reaquired object.
menuIn .close();
```

In you MainMenu change constructor to

```
public MainMenu(Scanner menuIn ){
```

And Remove below lines from the constructor

```
//Scanner menuIn = new Scanner(System.in);
//menuIn.close();
```